# Let users securely delete something in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, security, get

I'm trying to figure out how to let users securely delete their own ad that is in the database. I've written a delete script but it is not secure if you know other id's you can delete everything even though it is not your ad.

```
if (isset($_GET['ad'])) {
  $ID = $_GET['ad'];
  $objStmt = $objDatabaseo->prepare('DELETE FROM tabke WHERE id = :id');
  $objStmt->bindParam(':id', $ID);
  $objStmt->execute();
}
```

I've tried to compare it with the ID of the owner but that is still not safe enought. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance,

Bram.

Comment: `still not safe enough` why is that?

Comment: It does sound like a terrible idea. Are your ads related to logged in users somehow? if so, you should check whether or not the ad they're trying to delete belongs to them.

Comment: This script here will only protect against SQL injection.. You need to implement some authentication method for users of your application.

Comment: can you show the structure of the relevant tables?

Comment: @u_mulder I don't want the users to know which ID they have in the database.

Comment: If user ID is in session - it's on server side.

Comment: @u_mulder I know but I still need to send the ID to another page so it is visible in the url.

Comment: Id of what - of user? Why do you need to send it?

Comment: @u_mulder Now that you say that I know what to do. I actually don't have to send it because I can get it out of the session. Thanks :)